# cant choose a field from JSON when using variable

Tags: ruby

im trying to parse JSON what is respond from api what i request, but when im trying to choose a field from it using variable function returns me variable value.

```
@json = JSON.parse(request("smth"))
```

and in the same class (@json is in initialize function)

```
def custom args
        args.each do |arg|
          @json[arg]
        end
end
```

when im using smth = Class.new
and next smth.custom(['name'])
function returns me... name instead of name value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `args.each` iterates through every item in the array and then *returns the array*. Which means:

```
args.each do |arg|
  @json[arg]
end
```

Iterates through every item in `args` and then returns `args`. The part in the middle, `@json[arg]` is effectively doing nothing, since those values aren't returned.

If you want to retrieve the values, you need to add them to a new array and return that:

```
def custom args
  values = []
  args.each do |arg|
    values << @json[arg]
  end
  values
end
```

In Ruby, an easier way to do this is to use `map`, which creates an array based on another array's items:

```
def custom args
  args.map { |arg| @json[arg] }
end
```

If you want the `custom` method to return a hash with the `name: value` pairs of the names you specify, then you can use `select`:

```
def custom args
  @json.select { |k, v| args.include? k }
end
```

This goes through each item in the `@json` hash and returns a new hash with only the keys which are listed in `args`.

Comment: your values based version can just be `args.map {|arg| @json[arg] }` this will create a new array and return it

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you! I kept the code using `each` because I think it's important to show the OP how to make their own code work, when possible. But I'll go ahead and add your `map` code as well, because it's definitely the more elegant solution.